# Sort registered users by post count? (inside admin dashboard)

Tags: php, functions

By default, there's not option to sort users by Post count.

In case you are not sure, what I'm referring to is when you click on Users > All Users inside the WP Dashnoard.

I have tried searching all over the place but couldn't find the function for this simple, but yet important thing.

Can anyone throw me a bone, or paste the code if you have on your own Wordpress page?

I would greatly appreciate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following code:

```
add_filter('manage_users_sortable_columns', 'my_user_sortable_columns');
function my_user_sortable_columns($sortable_columns) {
    $sortable_columns['posts'] = 'post_count';
    return $sortable_columns;
}
```

Credit to: [Add additional user fields and make them sortable in the user screen](https://madebydenis.com/add-additional-user-fields-and-make-them-sortable-in-the-user-screen/)

Comment: hey Scott, thanks for the effort, but this doesn't sort by post count. When you click it sorts by username... Same as you would click on "Username" column.

Comment: hi Robert - used wrong code in my initial response, code snippet updated - try it again, should work as desired now.

Comment: Brilliant, worked like a charm, thanks a lot Scott!